# Javascript not validating fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, verification

I have the following code snippet.
For some reason the validation is not working.

I am trying to validate two things:

1. that no textfield is left empty
2. that the password field has at least 8 characters

if any of these is false, I should get an error. But this error message is never being shown.
Below is the snippet:

```js
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById("name").value == '') {
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").value=="You have forgotten to enter your name";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("surname").value == '') {
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").value == "You have forgotten to enter your surname";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("email").value == '') {
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").value == "You have forgotten to enter your email address";
    }
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#title{
    font: bold 20px Tahoma;
    color: white;
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}

#header{
 padding: 80px;
    font: 14px Tahoma;
}

body{
 width:100%;
 display:-webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
}

#main_container{
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 10px 0px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#control-container{
 display:-webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}

#label-container{
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 margin: 10px;
}

p {
    font: 14px Tahoma;
 margin: 20px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

#element-container{
 width: 500px;
 margin: 20px 0px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

#name{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
 margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

#surname{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

#email{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

#password{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f0000;
    border:1px solid #b20000;
}

input[type="text"]:hover{
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:hover{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f0000;
    border:1px solid #b20000;
}  

input[type="password"]:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f0000;
    border:1px solid #b20000;
}

input[type="password"]:hover{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

input[type="password"]:focus:hover{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f0000;
    border:1px solid #b20000;
    border-radius:0;
}  

#register{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
 margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#btnRegister {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Fastloader - Register for a new account</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
 <script src="register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "main-container">
 <header id = "header">
  <h1>Register for a new account<h1>
 </header>
    <div id= "control-container">
    <section id ="label-container">
        <p><label>Enter your Name:</label></p>
        <p><label>Enter your Surname:</label></p>
        <p><label>Enter your Email address:</label></p>
        <p><label>Choose a strong Password:</label></p>
    </section>
    
    <section id = "element-container">
        <div id = "name">            
            <input name="Name" type="text" id="name"/>
        </div>
        <div id = "surname">
            <input name="Surname" type="text" id="surname"/>
        </div>
        <div id = "email">
            <input name="Email" type="text" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div id = "password">
            <input name="Password" type="password" id = "password"/>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>
        <footer id = "register">
        <div id = "agreement">
            <label>I have read the Terms and Conditions:</label>
            <input name="agree" type="checkbox" id="agree" />
        </div>
            <div id = "error">
            <p><label id = "errorMsg"></label></p>
            </div>
        <div id = "button">
            <input type = "button" 
                   id="btnRegister" 
                   value = "Register" 
                   onclick="validate();"/>
        </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `return`, `false` when error, `true` otherwise in your validate function

Comment: did you mean `document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML` ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("errorMsg").value=="You have forgotten to enter your name";` that is a binary expression, not an assignment statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve it:

```js
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('name').value.length == 0) {
        alert("You have forgotten to enter your name");
    } else if (document.getElementById("surname").value.length == 0) {
        alert("You have forgotten to enter your surname");
    } else if (document.getElementById("email").value.length == 0) {
        alert("You have forgotten to enter your email address");
    }
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#title{
    font: bold 20px Tahoma;
    color: white;
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}

#header{
 padding: 80px;
    font: 14px Tahoma;
}

body{
 width:100%;
 display:-webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
}

#main_container{
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 10px 0px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#control-container{
 display:-webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}

#label-container{
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 margin: 10px;
}

p {
    font: 14px Tahoma;
 margin: 20px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

#element-container{
 width: 500px;
 margin: 20px 0px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

#name{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
 margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

#surname{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

#email{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

#password{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f0000;
    border:1px solid #b20000;
}

input[type="text"]:hover{
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:hover{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f0000;
    border:1px solid #b20000;
}  

input[type="password"]:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f0000;
    border:1px solid #b20000;
}

input[type="password"]:hover{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

input[type="password"]:focus:hover{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f0000;
    border:1px solid #b20000;
    border-radius:0;
}  

#register{
    font: 14px Tahoma;
 margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#btnRegister {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Fastloader - Register for a new account</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
 <script src="register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "main-container">
 <header id = "header">
  <h1>Register for a new account<h1>
 </header>
    <div id= "control-container">
    <section id ="label-container">
        <p><label>Enter your Name:</label></p>
        <p><label>Enter your Surname:</label></p>
        <p><label>Enter your Email address:</label></p>
        <p><label>Choose a strong Password:</label></p>
    </section>
    
    <section id = "element-container">
        <div id = "name_container">            
            <input name="Name" type="text" id="name"/>
        </div>
        <div id = "surname_container">
            <input name="Surname" type="text" id="surname"/>
        </div>
        <div id = "email_container">
            <input name="Email" type="text" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div id = "password_container">
            <input name="Password" type="password" id = "password"/>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>
        <footer id = "register">
        <div id = "agreement">
            <label>I have read the Terms and Conditions:</label>
            <input name="agree" type="checkbox" id="agree" />
        </div>
            <div id = "error">
            <p><label id = "errorMsg"></label></p>
            </div>
        <div id = "button">
            <input type = "button" 
                   id="btnRegister" 
                   value = "Register" 
                   onclick="validate();"/>
        </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById("errorMsg").value == "You have forgotten to enter your email address";
```

1. You used `==` which is for comparison, not for set new value. There you have to use only `=`
2. Label has no `value`, correct way is `.innerText`

Comment: I think the correct way is to use `.innerText` because it's a text, not html. `.innerHtml` works, but you'r using a function which is not mend to use like that.

Comment: still not working. I tried using an alert instead but this is still not showing. I am using Google Chrome

Comment: `document.getElementById("name")` doesn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: @AndreasFurster: you used id=name twice, the first one, `<div id=name>` has no `value`. ID has to be unique identifier, rename one of those elements.

Comment: Ah i see! Didn't saw it, but it's not mine question... :)

Comment: Hi @panther thanks for your insight. That was actually the problem. the name, surname, email and password ids were defined twice. Will post the correct answer soon.